# Cloudify manager to create instances on multiple cloud platforms

Tags: cloudify

I am trying to run cloudify outside of AWS and trying to create infrastructure on AWS. When installing agent, cloudify uses private IP address of the VM which I can't seem to override. Is there a way to run cloudify manager outside the AWS infrastructure and still be able to provision in AWS? 
Before you ask why I want to run cloudify outside the AWS, my main reason is that I want to manage multiple cloud platforms (AWS and Azure at the moment), and I don't want to run multiple cloudify managers. So if I install manager in AWS, I'll still have problem managing provisioning in Azure or openstack (which we may add later).

So the question is, how can I configure cloudify to use public (or provided) IP address to install agent, or not install agent at all (I just want to use cloudify to provision infrastructure), and I can use ansible to install my software. But if I say "install_method: none", it still complains about missing queue. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Altaf

Answer (score 0):

Cloudify does not support a method to use the public IP for manager-agent communications.

The recommended method is to configure a VPN between the Manager's host network and the target network. The classic example is if you are running a Cloudify Manager on your laptop and you want to provision AWS resources. AWS offers a feature called [VPN Connection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html) which makes it easy to configure a VPN to your AWS VPC. If you wanted to have a manager in Azure, you can do the same thing with a VPN Server running in Azure.

Comment: What if we pre-install the cloudify agent on the VM, do we still need VPN connection? Not sure if manager and agent directly communicate or talk through MQ. If this could work, how to install cloudify agent (using commands).